# Is this kind of logic possible using CAML Queries?

Tags: sharepoint, caml, spservices

I am fairly experienced with CAML Queries, but this one has me stuck. I need some help in structuring the query's logic.
What I need is to return every record that that contains two words across two columns.

Example (return these):

- Column1: word1, Column2: word2. //Return this record
- Column1: word2, Column2: word1. //Return this record
- Column1: word2 word1, Column2: (empty). //Return this record
- Column1: (empty), Column2: word2 word1. //Return this record

Example (do not return these):

- Column1: (empty), Column2: word1. // Do not return this record
- Column1: word1, Column2: (empty). // Do not return this record
- Column1: (empty), Column2: word2. // Do not return this record
- Column1: word2, Column2: (empty). // Do not return this record
- Column1: (empty), Column2: (empty). // Do not return this record

To put the logic in sudo-code:
if( ("word1" appears in 'Column1' OR "word1" appears in 'Column2') AND ("word2" appears in 'Column1' OR "word2" appears in 'Column2') ) 
I have tried different variations of queries, but they do not return desirable results. For example, the one below will always return a record if word1 appears in Column1 even if word2 does not appear anywhere.

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Column1"/><Value Type="Text">word1</Value>
        </Contains>
        <And>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name="Column2"/><Value Type="Text">word1</Value>
            </Contains>
            <Or>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name="Column1"/><Value Type="Text">word2</Value>
                </Contains>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name="Column2"/><Value Type="Text">word2</Value>
                </Contains>
            </Or>
        </And>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

P.S. I am in SharePoint 2007 using SPServices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to spevilgenius on spservices.codeplex.com, here is what worked for me:

```
<And>
    <Or>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Column1"/><Value Type="Text">word1</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Column2"/><Value Type="Text">word1</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Or>
    <Or>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Column1"/><Value Type="Text">word2</Value>
        </Contains>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Column2"/><Value Type="Text">word2</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Or>
</And>
```

Link to discussion:
https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/637384